# Receive input in specific time

Tags: java

I'm writing a testing system and i all i want to do is to count how many seconds had user spent on this question. i.e. i print question(standard System.out.println), then wait 5 seconds and if within these 5 seconds user answered(through standard input), i want to keep this value.

If user hasn't provided an answer in 5 seconds, it must skip this question and continue.

The problem is I'm reading user answers via `Scanner` object, and something like `in.nextInt()` is uncontrollable, I suppose.

How can I solve this problem? Here is fragment of my code without that functionality, can you give me some hints what to add?

```
    public void start() {
    questions.prepareQuestions(numQuestions);
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean playerIsRight=false,botIsRight=false;
    int playerScore=0,botScore=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numQuestions; i++) {
        questions.askQuestion(i);
        System.out.print("Your answer(number): ");
        playerIsRight=questions.checkAnswer(i,in.nextInt()-1); //in.nextInt() contains the answer
        botIsRight=botAnswersCorrectly(i + 1);
        if(playerIsRight){ playerScore++; System.out.println("Correct!");}
        else System.out.println("Incorrect!");
        if(botIsRight) botScore++;
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
    if(botScore>playerScore) System.out.println("Machine won! Hail to the almighty transistors!");
    else if(playerScore>botScore) System.out.println("Human won! Hail to the power of nature!");
    else System.out.println("Tie. No one ever wins. No one finally loses.");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use two threads in this case. The main thread writes questions, waits for answers, and keeps score. A child thread reads standard input and sends the answers to the main thread, perhaps via a [`BlockingQueue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).

The main thread can wait for five seconds for an answer by using the `poll()` method on the blocking queue:

```
…
BlockingQueue<Integer> answers = new SynchronousQueue();
Thread t = new ReaderThread(answers);
t.start();
for (int i = 0; i < numQuestions; ++i) {
  questions.askQuestion(i);
  System.out.print("Your answer (number): ");
  Integer answer = answers.poll(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  playerIsRight = (answer != null) && questions.checkAnswer(i, answer - 1); 
  …
}
t.interrupt();
```

If this call returns `null`, the main thread knows that the child thread didn't receive any input during that time, and can update the score appropriately and print the next question.

The `ReaderThread` would look something like this:

```
class ReaderThread extends Thread {

  private final BlockingQueue<Integer> answers;

  ReaderThread(BlockingQueue<Integer> answers) { 
    this.answers = answers; 
  }

  @Override 
  public void run() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (!Thread.interrupted()) 
      answers.add(in.nextInt());
  }

}
```

Used on `System.in`, the `Scanner` will block until the user presses `Enter`, so it might happen that the user has entered some text but not yet pressed `Enter` when the main thread times out and moves on to the next question. The user would have to delete their pending entry and enter a new answer for the new question. I don't know of a clean way around this awkwardness, since there's not a reliable way to interrupt the `nextInt()` call.

Comment: It can be lame, but what if i will start a new thread after asking a question, call wait(timeout) and in new thread i will wait for answer and after receiving it, i will call notify() on object in parent thread. Will it work?

Comment: You could roll your own solution using using `wait` and `notify`, but as you've seen, it's tricky to get it right. Using a `BlockingQueue` is roughly equivalent, but it's bundled in a clean, reliable package.

Comment: Im working now with your solution, and i dont understand one thing: do i have to put all cycle between t.start/t.interrupt, or only input reading part? Because it doesnt seem to work the way you wrote in your snuppet.

Comment: @Anton - the stuff inside your original `for` loop should be in the new loop. That's what the ... is. When you say it doesn't seem to work, can you describe exactly what you are seeing?

Comment: I expect to finish my current job in c++ and get back to java on monday, so i will post my code and tell you what i see. Please, dont leave this thread cuz i need your help :)

Comment: It works! Looks like i was doing something wrong the last time i tried. Thanks!